# FFT padding to power of 2

Tags: fft, zero-padding

I have a vector v1 of size N1, I want to pad it in a certain way until it reaches a size power of 2 (v2 of size N2). I need that the first N1 coefficients of the FFT output to stay the same as when I would apply FFT(v1), is that possible? If so, how to?

Answer (score 2):

Most often the reason to pad to a power of 2 is for efficient implementation where everything is can be done with radix-2 butterflies.

When zero padding is employed on M samples out to N bins the additional DFT frequency samples are interpolated. It may help with intuition to know that any DFT samples are samples on the Discrete Time Fourier Transform which is what would result if the time domain waveform were allowed to extend to infinity (zero pad out to infinity and the frequency response becomes a continuous waveform, any less than infinity and the frequency response is sampled-- so the more zeros that are added, the  more that the underlying continuous DTFT is sampled as additional interpolated samples).

Here is a simple example. Consider the time domain waveform given as [1 1 1 1], the DFT for this is [4 0 0 0]. if we zero pad out to $N = 1024$ total samples and plot the result we get the following and we see that the samples [4 0 0 0] do land on this underlying waveform but only because the new number of samples $N = 1024$ is an integer multiple of the original $M=4$ number of samples:

[image: DFT no padding]

Here is a second case with the integer relationship, in this case padded out to $N = 16$ samples and compared to with the 1024 padding what appears at this resolution to be the continuous DTFT. Note that 16 samples is an integer multiple of the original 4 samples, and in fact multiplied by 4. Further we see that the original DFT result [4 0 0 0] is recovered simply by selecting every fourth sample:

[image: DFT padding to 16 samples]

Finally consider an example that is not so straightforward, where the padding is not out to an integer multiple of samples, such as 17 samples compare to the case above:

[image: DFT 17 samples]

We see how all the samples still always lie on the underlying DTFT regardless of the amount of zero padding, but only when we pad out to an integer multiple $N/M = D$ will the Dth samples of the padded DFT be the exact value of the original DFT with no padding. For other cases we can make assumptions about the underlying DTFT to estimate via interpolation an approximation of what the values are (which would still be at the fractional locations given by $N/M$) but without further knowledge of the actual waveform the exact values will not be recoverable in these non-integer cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but it is usually less complex to do the FFT of size `n1`.

To be honest given the FFT of a signal of size `N1` padded to `N2`, the most efficient way that comes to my mind to find the coefficients of an FFT of the same signal without padding is to do the inverse FFT of the signal, removing the padding and do the FFT of size `N1` with those clever libraries such as fftw.

Why?

Let $p(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{N_1-1} x_i \exp(2j \pi f k)$, the FFT of size $N_1$ is $p(n_1/N_1)$ but the FFT of size $N_2$ (with the padded signal) will give you $p(n_2/N_2)$.

So let's see for which $n_1$ we find solutions with integer $n_2$

$$\frac{n_1}{N_1} = \frac{n_2}{N_2}$$

it turns out that $n_2 = n_1 N_2 / N_1$, let $N_2 = 2^{a_2}$ and $N_1 = 2^{a_1} b$ for an odd $b$. Then we have $n_2 = n_1 2^{a_2 - a_1} / b$, i.e. only the coefficients at indices multiples of $b$.

In a more general way we could say that only the coefficients with indices multiples of $N_1 / \gcd(N_1, N_2)$ can be recovered.